# Wirless Network Connection fails

Tags: wifi-configuration

**problem**: after installing Windows Server 2008 R2 on my Toshiba laptop (for development) I cant get my wifi connection to work.

**details**:

- RealTek RTL81888CE Wireless LAN 802.11n
- PCI-E NIC PCI bus 6, device 0, function 0, working properly
- 802.11d disabled Beacon
- Interval 100 Preamble Mode Short&Long
- Roaming Sensitivity Level Low
- TX Power Level Auto Wireless Mode Auto
- Driver: 20-4-2011 ; 1005.19.420.2011 (rtl8192Ce.sys) (latest) (https://aps.toshiba-tro.de/wlan/?page=downloads)
- Laptop Tosiba Satellite C660-1DG
- device manager shows the device no prob
- there is no other vendor specific util installed
- no specific firewall installed yet only default windows firewall

The card is recognized, shows as no problems, regular DHCP (auto), ipconfig /all does not show the connection.

Comment: Does `IPconfig /all` show the adapter at all?

Comment: nope it does not even show it

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me. (I will leave it for reference for others to find):

I needed to add the Wireless Lan Service as feature in Windows Server 2008 R2.
See: http://www.mydigitallife.info/enable-wireless-wi-fi-in-windows-server-2008-r2-to-fix-no-connections-available-error/